# Mesh lines in the shape of a circle do not render in my model

Tags: rendering, mesh, export

I have a 'Solar System' model for my website, I have already placed the spheres that represent the sun and the planets, and I have also added unfilled circles that represent the orbits, I have created these in add > mesh > circle, too I have animated the entire model, when I finished it looked like this:

[image: Modeling...]

The problem is that when I move to the 'animate' section, the circles that represent the orbits disappear, even though the objects continue to exist in scene > collection:

[image: Animating]

Even when I export my model in .glb format to use on my website, I am able to render the scene but the circles still do not appear, although the object that is created when importing the .glb contains all the figures in the scene:

[image: Imbibing...]

Any help is welcome, I'm new to this. I use Blender 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edges on their own don’t show up in renders. They can be converted to curves which can be given thickness.

1. Select the orbit line
2. In the *Object* menu Choose *Convert > Curve*
3. In the *Data* tab of the *Properties* panel, find the *Geometry* section and set the *Bevel Depth* to something like `0.04`
4. You should see the edge curve sort of "inflate" into something like a ring

Comment: That's it! thanks bro